# Passbook automated test

Tags: ios, objective-c, testing, automated-tests, passbook

I'm developing a product with passbook push.

I'm wondering if and how all steps in the use of passbok can be automated tested ?

For example : automatically scan and add a passbook, then check if the passbook is valid, and when the passbook push new data (via APNS push), assert that the notification is received.

Thank you !

Xero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Xero In fact, you can do a number of checks to the `.passbook` file itself. Remembering that it's just an archive, you can do the following, for example:

1. Assert that passbook file is not empty
2. Assert that file unzips successfully
3. Assert that the required files are present (e.g. `pass.json`, `manifest.json`, `signature`)
4. Assert that files are not empty
5. Assert that JSON in the files is valid/contains expected info.

So, while using the file probably can't (or not worth to) be automated, *validity* of the file can be quite thoroughly tested with unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot automate some process; scan to add pass into passbook and delete pass from paasbook.

You can automate only push new data with/without notification.